# spl_autoloader not loading any classes

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

so i've started using namespaces and read some docs but I seem to be doing something wrong.

First off is my application structure which is build like this:

```
root
-dashboard(this is where i want to use the autoloader)
-index.php
--config(includes the autoloader)
--WePack(package)
---src(includes all my classes)
```

now in the src directory I included the classes with:

```
namespace WePack\src;
class Someclass(){

}
```

the content of config.php is:

```
<?php
// Start de sessie
ob_start();
session_start();

// Locate application path
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
set_include_path(ROOT);
spl_autoload_extensions(".php"); // comma-separated list
spl_autoload_register();
echo get_include_path();
```

and I use it like this in my index.php

```
require_once ('config/config.php');
use WePack\src;
$someclass = new Someclass;
```

this is what the echo get_include_path(); returns:

```
/home/wepack/public_html/dashboard
```

which is what I want I guess. but the classes are not loaded and nothing is happening. I'm obviously missing something but I can't seem to figure it out. could you guys take a look at it and explain to me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is, that you don't register a callback function with `spl_autoload_register()`. have a look at the official [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

To be more flexible, you can write your own class to register and autoload classes like this:

```
class Autoloader
{
    private $baseDir = null;

    private function __construct($baseDir = null)
    {
        if ($baseDir === null) {
            $this->baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
        } else {
            $this->baseDir = rtrim($baseDir, '');
        }
    }

    public static function register($baseDir = null)
    {
        //create an instance of the autoloader
        $loader = new self($baseDir);

        //register your own autoloader, which is contained in this class
        spl_autoload_register(array($loader, 'autoload'));

        return $loader;
    }

    private function autoload($class)
    {
        if ($class[0] === '\\') {
            $class = substr($class, 1);
        }

        //if you want you can check if the autoloader is responsible for a specific namespace
        if (strpos($class, 'yourNameSpace') !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        //replace backslashes from the namespace with a normal directory separator
        $file = sprintf('%s/%s.php', $this->baseDir, str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class));

        //include your file
        if (is_file($file)) {
            require_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

after this you'll register your autoloader like this:

```
Autoloader::register("/your/path/to/your/libraries");
```

Comment: i removed the namespace in the classfile and it started working. but i want to use namespaces

Comment: what exactly do you pass to the register function? I'm using this with a lot of namespaces, but have an additional condition to load the class only if the first namespace is mine.

Comment: Autoloader::register("/home/wealert/public_html/dashboard/WeAlert/src"); and tried using classes with $template   = new Template; and $template   = new WeAlert\src\Template;

Comment: ok, try to use just `Autoloader::register("/home/wealert/public_html/dashboard");` and maybe you want to ouptut the `$file` variable in the autoload method to find out whats wrong.

Comment: it works with the "/home/wealert/public_html/dashboard/src" but only if i don't set 'namespace WeAlert\src;' in the Template.php file

Comment: what does $file look like if you pass in the namespace? do a simple `var_dump($file)` in the method `autoload($class)` before you include the file

Comment: It started working with Autoloader::register("/home/wealert/public_html/dashboard"); and calling the class with $template   = new WeAlert\src\Template; but i'm getting a different error now when trying to set up a mysqli connection string(58) "/home/wealert/public_html/dashboard/WeAlert/src/mysqli.php"
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'WeAlert\src\mysqli' not found in <b>/home/wealert/public_html/dashboard/WeAlert/src/Connection.php</b> on line <b>20</b> probably because of this in connection.php $db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you mean:

```
spl_autoload_register(function( $class ) {
    include_once ROOT.'/classes/'.$class.'.php';
});
```

That way you can just call a class like:

```
$user = new User(); // And loads it from "ROOT"/classes/User.php
```

Comment: so what would be the use of namespaces in this case? and how can i use an extra library with the same loader but different file structure

Comment: Since I don't have experience with namespaces I can't give you an complete answer on that. But it should still be working much in the same way. I think that if you would use `use \User $user = new User()` it would still work. And with "extra library" do you mean something like PHPmailer?

Comment: hmm no since phpmailer existed before namespaces it doesn't use it, more like library's such as Ivory and Geocoder-php